# I can't connect to mysql using sqlyog, but I can connect to mysql using sql.exe?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I have set up mysql-server on my ubuntu server.
And I have notes my.cnf as

```
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

to allow all client to login.And on my ubuntu server,I login mysql to grant all root user that from any client can login.
I execute

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "myrootpassword"
```

then I can login mysql from my computer using sql.exe
It successed

[image]

but I want to use sqlyog to login, It's failed why?

[image]

Comment: hey can you please make sure the port is added in windows firewall? If not  just go ahead and add the port. This should solve u r problem.

Comment: @SathishD port 3306 is available.I can telnet from my computer,it's available

Comment: Yes.. but even then try to add that port in windows firewall. Also let me know what is the type of connection that you are using? direct/HTTP/SSH ?

Comment: It's my fault I filled out the wrong password in sqlyog.thanks all